What is the grammatical construction of "have something hanging out"?

I haven’t heard any negative comments although some people think he’s really tired and has it hanging out from exhaustion.

Source: https://metro.co.uk/2021/05/21/dog-has-tongue-so-long-it-trails-on-the-floor-when-he-goes-for-a-walk-14622287/

She said of the dog, who always has his tongue hanging out: ‘I want to get his tongue pierced.

Source: https://metro.co.uk/2016/05/17/carrie-fisher-wants-to-get-her-diva-dogs-tongue-pierced-5887479/
"has it hanging out" and "has his tongue hanging out" have the same grammatical construction.
In the second text, if his tongue had already been mentioned, we could have substituted "his tongue" with "it".

Is "hanging out" part of a reduced relative clause in the two texts.
What are the grammatical constructions of "has it hanging" and "has his tongue hanging out"?


To have something [complement]
means to have it in the state expressed by [complement].

You have that picture crooked.
She had her hair in a bun.
The dog had its tongue hanging out.
You have your zipper down.
You have your shirt unbuttoned.
The child had his shoes untied.
You have it assembled wrong. You have it pointing up and it's supposed to be pointing down.
She had the figurines arranged in a straight line.


When I saw the title I thought it was going to be about something else, but, happily, it is not.
